# Hide Error : image not found or type unknown dompdf php

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

How to hide error message in dompdf when image was not found? I want to display blank box when image could not found.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any code.

A solution is to have a temp image if other images aren't found.

A quick answer is:

```
 if(!$image){

 $image = $temp_image;

   }
```